# In python, how to hide sensitive data from getting exposed in memory dump?

Tags: python, security, memory-dump

In windows platform, python application data is getting exposed in the memory dump.
Memory dump is taken by using process hacker tool.

```
def f1(self):
        # some code
        id = "<sensitive_string_data>"
        return
```

If above example is considered, the value of id i.e., `<sensitive_string_data>` is exposed in the memory dump.

Is there any way to mark such variables as sensitive and hide it from memory dump?

Tried 3 options, but no use.

1. by deleting the variable after its use
2. by pointing the variable to None
3. by deleting the variable and performing gc.collect()

Answer (score 0):

Python does not offer low level memory control or direct control over memory management.